# VS2012 button "Show all files" not showing all files

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssis

I am using Visual Studio 2012 to create SSIS packages. And I have some files in my .dtsx files in my project folder (showing side-by-side with the other .dtsx files in File Explorer) which are not part of my project.

Now I would like to include these files in my project, so in VS2012 I have marked my project and click the "Show All Files" button. I can see that the button is pressed, but my files are not showing up in my SSIS Packages folder (or anywhere else for that matter).

I know that I can manually move the files outside my project and the "Add existing item" and add the files in that way. And that would be fine if it was only this one time. But my problem is that we are two developers working on the project. And everytime the other developer adds a file, I have to do this manually.

Anyone who has an idea on how to fix this?